# I accidentally typed dc instead of cd into terminal

Tags: bash, stack, cd

I was going through a Ruby lesson and accidentally typed dc instead of cd into the terminal.
Now when I try to access the programs folder on my desktop using the following commands

```
cd;
cd Desktop;
cd programs
```

The path is not showing ups as Desktop/programs

Instead it is only showing up as programs in the terminal as a result I can't access the text wrangler file.

Did I mess something up when I accidentally typed dc? And if so I can I restore the default?

Comment: dc stands for desk calculator and you can use q to quit that window.

Comment: @GhostRider: Or Ctl-D, or Ctl-C.

Comment: yes. can use any of the commands to exit that.. thanx

Comment: @GhostRider: My point, or part of it, is that Ctl-D is more general (it should work for any command that reads from standard input), and Ctl-C is even more so (it should work for any command that doesn't take steps to handle Ctl-C internally). `q` happens to be the `dc` command to quit, but you'd have to know `dc` to know that.

Comment: @KeithThompson totally agree

Comment: Since this isn't a programming question, it really should have been posted to [unix.se] or perhaps [su], but it's too old to migrate.

Answer (score 4):

Just typing `dc` will run the `dc` (desk calculator) command. It's hard to tell what's going on, because we don't know what you did after running the `dc` command. If `ls` is showing you file listings, then you've already left `dc` and you're back in your shell. (`dc` doesn't show a prompt; the shell does.)

`dc` happens to accept `q` as a command to tell it to quit, but more generally if you've executed a command you didn't mean to, <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> will terminate a command that reads from standard input, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> will generate an interrupt that will terminate any command that doesn't handle it, and <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> will suspend the current program (run `jobs` to see a list of suspended programs).

Or, as a last resort, you can close your terminal and launch a new one.

It would be more helpful if you'd show us (copy-and-paste) the commands you're typing and their output.

The problem most likely is that your current directory isn't the one you want or expect it to be. `pwd` shows you what the current directory is; `cd` changes the current directory to what you specify (or to your home directory if you type `cd` without an argument).

(Incidentally, you don't need to type a semicolon at the end of each command. Semicolons can be used to separate multiple commands on one line.)